# Digits of Pi Distribution Using Kolmogorov Smirnov Test

Tags: r, uniform-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov

I would like to perform the following test in R using the Kolmogorov Smirnov Test:

1) The occurence of the various integers in the first 4000 decimal places of pi  is as follows:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
368 426 408 374 405 415 398 376 400 430
```

Test the null hypothesis that the occurrence of various integers follows a uniform distribution, as if pi were a random number.

Attempt:

I obtained the cumulative probability density function and set it as x.

```
x <- c(.092,.1985,.3005,.394,.49525,.599,.6985,.7925,.8925,1)

ks.test(x,y="punif")
```

This outputs:

```
One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.1005, p-value = 0.9996
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

However, doing it by hand gives D=.008. What did I do wrong?

Hand calculation:

Assuming uniformity we would have the following cdf:

```
.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1
```

I then found the absolute value of the difference between these values and x as I defined above to get a max difference of .008.

Comment: can you say more about the procedure you used to do it by hand?

Comment: Yes, I will add that

Answer (score 1):

There might be a couple of problems here.

First, `ks.test` wants its argument to be "a numeric vector of **data values**" (my emphasis), not a summary of the distribution. So the input should be something like.

```
pi_digits <- rep(0:9,c(368,426,408,374,405,415,398,376,400,430))
```

Second, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is designed to test the distance between two *continuous* probability distributions. So when I tried to put in the values above, I got a warning about ties.

Comment: Oh okay. I just learned about this test in class today so maybe he showed us a discrete example for simplification.